# Always show slash before directory name in prompt

Tags: bash, prompt

if I am in: /1/2/3 I want prompt to show:

```
user /3:
```

If I am in : /  I want the prompt to show:

```
user /:
```

This does not work  ( when in /1/2/3 ) ( no slash )

```
PS1="\u \W: "
```

This does not work ( when in / )  ( shows double / )

```
PS1="\u /\W: "
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? It looks like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @dr01, base folder with a slash. my mind is not really configured to believe /folder equates to a folder in the /. the slash also helps seperate the username from the foldername. easier on the eyes.

Comment: The shell prompt will be the same whether you're in `/home/penguen/stuff-to-delete/etc` or in `/etc`.  May (and likely will) be source of troubles.

Comment: @dr01, it would be just a visual thing. I would know where I probably am.

Comment: When your mind eventually reconfigure, you will hate what you have done.

Comment: @richard, you are making the assumption that linux is perfect. if it was perfect "printf aaa" would not shove the "aaa" to the behind of the "user" in the user prompt.

Comment: @user218169, that is `bash` that handles `printf`, not `linux`. By the way what would you like it to do? It could add a newline (like basic), but this is a pain, because now you can not print without a new-line. So what should it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use:

```
PS1='${USER=$(LOGNAME)} /${PWD##*/}: '
```

(which would also work in most other Bourne-like shells).